# Workflow status, Access Denied

Tags: workflow

I hope someone can help me here.

I get the following when i enter data to a list, with a workflow that simply replaces permissions for the submitter.

> Work Flow status: Canceled
>
> Event: Error 
> Event Type: Error
> User ID: System Account   
> Description: Failed to update permissions. 
> Outcome: Access Denied

Will appreciate any advice anyone can give.

Comment: Add more details on how the workflow is created

Comment: Hi Amal

Its a simple step really.

Impersonation Step

Replace Contribute (for a staff member group) of the item in Current List

(i have them slected the ID field and Current List ID value to select the list)


IT just seems to fail as it says system account does not have access... although i have added it